# Can't find marketplace client for Eclipse oxygen version milestone 6

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, eclipse-oxygen

I'm unable to find the Eclipse Marketplace in the Help Menu for Eclipse Oxygen version milestone 6. I've seen it last in Mars version in my old system. As I moved to a new system I installed a new version of eclipse which is Oxygen version. But this version doesn't seem to have marketplace client installed with it. How can I find it or install the plugin from external sources?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and won't be finally released until June 2017. Many additions may not have been tested with Oxygen at this point. Eclipse Neon.3 is the current stable release.

Answer (score 13):

This is the problem with latest eclipse to prevent bloating. So go to Eclipse-> Help--> Install New software and --> type Oxygen in the "Work with" space (or copy paste this "Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen".)

Now search "Market place client" in the second search box .

You will get as below: General purpose tools-->Market place client. Check that box and you are good to go.

Comment: Do the above with JAVA 7 and then install market place--> Java 8 support for Oxygen. Else you will still not be able to see Marketplace option in Help section.

Comment: If I install Java 7, I'm unable to start the eclipse itself. I had encountered IllegalStateException, which I tried resolving by all possible solutions on stackoverflow but couldn't do it.

Comment: I am using Oxygen.2 (4.7.2).  It appears that Marketplace Client is included with the default installation.  The "Eclipse Marketplace..." menu option is already present in the Help menu.  So, no need to go through this process.

Comment: I had to un-check the "Hide items that are already installed" box to see that the plugin was already installed.

However, I don't see anything about "marketplace" in the help menu.